# Differential Operators and Coefficients

Tags: partial-differential-equations, operator-algebras, laplacian, differential-operators

First question on Math StackExchange here. I have been staring at this for a bit, but wasn't quite able to get the hang of it. Here it goes.

We are given
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial}{\partial x} = \cos{\theta}\frac{\partial}{\partial r} - \frac{\sin{\theta}}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}.
\end{align}

We would like to square this operator to get
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} & = \Big[\cos{\theta}\frac{\partial}{\partial r} - \frac{\sin{\theta}}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} \Big]^2 \\\\
& = \Big(\cos{\theta}\frac{\partial}{\partial r} - \frac{\sin{\theta}}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} \Big) \Big(\cos{\theta}\frac{\partial}{\partial r} - \frac{\sin{\theta}}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} \Big)  \\\\
& = \cos^2{\theta} \frac{\partial^2}{\partial r^2} - 2 \Big(\frac{\sin{\theta}\cos{\theta}}{r} \Big) \frac{\partial^2}{\partial r \partial \theta} + \frac{\sin^2{\theta}}{r^2} \frac{\partial^2}{\partial \theta^2} + \frac{2\sin{\theta}\cos{\theta}}{r^2} \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} + \frac{\sin^2{\theta}}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}
\end{align}

Now here's the part that I don't get. To me first three terms on the last line make perfect sense. But instead of stopping there, squaring the operator gives the last two terms, which I don't understand. My guess is that it has to do with the coefficients, but I would like to know exactly how this works.

To be more even specific, my question reduces to

\begin{align}
\Big( \cos{\theta} \frac{\partial}{\partial r} \Big) \Big(-\frac{\sin{\theta}}{r} \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} \Big)
\end{align}

What does this equal and why? The more detailed the explanation, the better.

To provide some context, this was part of a step to show the two-dimensional Laplace operator in polar coordinates in a PDE textbook.

Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These terms come from applying the **product rule** when multiplying out the operators: For example, the *outer* terms read as
$$\left(\cos\theta\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\right)\left(-\frac{\sin\theta}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}\right)=-\cos\theta\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left(\frac{\sin\theta}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}\right)
$$
You must then apply the product rule to the $\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left(\frac{\sin\theta}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}\right)$ term since you are taking the $r$ derivative of the product $\frac{\sin\theta}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}$, giving
$$-\cos\theta\left[\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left(\frac{\sin\theta}{r}\right)\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}+\frac{\sin\theta}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}\right)\right]
=-\cos\theta\left(-\frac{\sin\theta}{r^2}\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}+\frac{\sin\theta}{r}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial r\partial\theta}\right)=\ ...$$

Hope that clarifies those extra terms.

Comment: I am sorry but I am confusing myself - do you think you could write the steps out in full?

Comment: I wrote them out a couple of times myself, and am getting a different answer from what was in the book. Thanks again.

Comment: @mathsquestions1, do these edits help clarify?

Comment: What happens when you multiply the -cos? Chain rule again?

Comment: There's no chain rule happening, just the product rule when multiplying the differential operators through. Multiply the $-\cos\theta$ through in the last expression and compare to the terms in the right-hand-side of your equation

Comment: I think I'm very close to understanding this. Does this mean the following? $-\cos{\theta} \Big( -\frac{\sin{\theta}}{r^2} \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} + \frac{\sin{\theta}}{r} \frac{\partial^2}{\partial r \partial \theta} \Big) = \frac{\cos{\theta}\sin{\theta}}{r^2} \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} - \frac{\cos{\theta}\sin{\theta}}{r}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial r \partial \theta}$

Comment: Or this:
$-\cos{\theta} \Big( -\frac{\sin{\theta}}{r^2} \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} + \frac{\sin{\theta}}{r} \frac{\partial^2}{\partial r \partial \theta} \Big) = \frac{\cos{\theta}\sin{\theta}}{r^2} \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} - \frac{\sin^2{\theta}}{r^2} - \frac{\cos{\theta}\sin{\theta}}{r}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial r \partial \theta}$

Comment: Yes, the one I upvoted. Multiplying by $\cos\theta$ is just multiplying by $\cos$. When you multiply through by a differential operator, "multiplication" is really just "take the derivative", that's why you have to use the product rule when multiplying the $\frac{\partial}{\partial r}$ through

Comment: Amazing!! Thank you so much for the help!!